# MYSQL JOIN with MAX() value of ENUM

Tags: mysql, sql, join, enums, max

I have tow tables in my database:

```
user_id | user_name
--------+----------
1       |jim
2       |john

user_id | status
--------+----------
1       |ONE
2       |TWO
1       |THREE
```

The status is an enum, defined like that:

```
status enum('ONE','TWO','THREE') NOT NULL
```

This should garantee that ONE is the lowest status and THREE the highest. Im retrieving the status of a user in the following way:

```
 SELECT user_id, type, status, event_date, valid_from, valid_to
 FROM status_event
 WHERE user_id = 1
 ORDER BY status DESC
 LIMIT 1;
```

This gives me, like expected, the status THREE as order by is using the order of the status.

Now I want to write SQL to retrieve a list of all users and their highest status value. Im having trouble as the MAX() funtion is evidently comparing the status values as strings and returning TWO as max. Furthermore, I have no idea how to join them, is it possible to do this? Do I need a subquery?

The result I want is the following:

```
user_name| status
---------+----------
jim      |THREE
john     |TWO
```

Comment: You can create the enum value as **integer**, So order by will work properly. As currently it is as **string** and Two and Three both start with **T** .

Comment: ORDER BY is working properly, MAX() is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL has a known bug with `MAX()`/`MIN()`and enums -- using the string value rather than the integer value.  This bug does not apply to `ORDER BY`.  (I don't know if this has been fixed in recent versions).

But, you can accomplish what you want.  If you wanted the rows with the highest status:

```
SELECT se.*
FROM status_event se
WHERE se.status = (SELECT se2.status
                   FROM status_event se2
                   WHERE se2.user_id = se.user_id
                   ORDER BY se2.status DESC
                   LIMIT 1
                  );
```

For a single row per user:

```
SELECT DISTINCT se.user_id, se.status
FROM status_event se
WHERE se.status = (SELECT se2.status
                   FROM status_event se2
                   WHERE se2.user_id = se.user_id
                   ORDER BY se2.status DESC
                   LIMIT 1
                  );
```

Answer (score 1):

as you probably know the MAX and ORDER BY on the enum work with **String** and not with **int**.

Try to edit you query removing the `limit 1` and selecting only the `status`.
You'll see that the proper order is not given.
This is the order by status DESC of the enum:
TWO, THREE, ONE.

So both the order by and max() works with string.

My suggestion is to use an INT instead of a VARCHAR for the statuses.

> Furthermore, I have no idea how to join them, is it possible to do this? Do I need a subquery?

With a nested query you can retrieve the Max value for an integer enum, and put this retrieved value in the outer query where condition.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to create an "enum mapping" table that maps each value of the enum to a integer.  You can then join that table to your query and use MIN of the integer value rather than the enum.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).